# How to compare two columns and extract a match based on a condition?

Tags: python

I have two columns **arrival** and **departure** for airplanes:

My program asks the user for two lists:

- Which departure airports do you want?
- Which arrival airports do you want?

I need to go through the two columns, and extract the rows in which departure airports from the departure list that a user gave me match with an arrival airport from the arrival list.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I thought I included it.

Comment: I don't understand the row numbers you have given in your example. Rows or what? 'JFK' is the 2nd item (index 1) in `departure_input_list`.

Comment: The indices refer to the orginal data set of departure and arrival, not to the input lists.

Comment: So you need all rows, where one of the codes from departure_list is in departure columns OR where one of the codes in arrival_list is in arrival column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `departure` and `arrival` are the same length, and thus the same-index entry in `departure` corresponds to that index entry in `arrival`, you only need to iterate through once::

```
num_flights = len(arrival)  # should equal len(departure)
common_indices = [i for i in range(num_flights) if departure[i] in departure_input_list and arrival[i] in arrival_input_list]
```

Note the `if` condition - we check both if the departure is acceptable and if the arrival is acceptable, and we do them separately from each other but at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.Series.isin` with `iloc`:

```
df.loc[df['departure'].isin(departure_input_list) & df['arrival'].isin(arrival_input_list)]
```

Output:

```
  departure arrival
3       JFK     BHL
5       LGB     BHL
6       LGA     WHP
7       NYC     WTC
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work.

```
# Source
departure = ['SAT','LAX','BDL','JFK','MCO','LGB','LGA','NYC','BOS']
arrival = ['SJU','LAX','BOS','BHL','EWR','BHL','WHP','WTC','LSQ']

# input
dep_input = ['FLU', 'JFK', 'JPB', 'JRA','JRE', 'LGA', 'NYC']
arr_input = ['BHL', 'LAX', 'LSQ', 'WHP']

source_dict = dict(zip(departure, arrival))
arrival_set = set(arr_input)  # converting to set for better performance O(1)
result_dep = filter(lambda x : source_dict.get(x, '') in arrival_set , dep_input)
print map(lambda y : (y, source_dict[y]) , result_dep)
```